# Pictures in XML (Show in html)

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have created image paths in XML and now want to display them in HTML. However, they will not appear on my HTML page and I do not know where the error lies. What am I doing wrong?

My test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<memory>
    <cardTuple>
        <img1>/1/1.png</img1>
    </cardTuple>
</memory>
```

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <img id="img1" src="" alt=""/>
        <script src="bilder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript bilder.js :

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

const parser = new DOMParser();

const cardTuples = xml.getElementsByTagName("memory")[0].childNodes; // Array<CardTuple>
const randomCardTuples = shuffle(cardTuples);

const cardTuple1 = randomCardTuples[0]; // cardtuple #1
const urlBild1 = cardTuple1.getElementsByTagName('img1')[0].nodeValue; // ./1.png

const imgTag1 = document.getElementById('img1'); // <img id='img1'>
imgTag1.src = urlBild1;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Could you show more relevant code of your `bilder.js` file? Are you fetching the XML from the server with JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have edited the rest of the Javascript file. No, the files are all in one folder. It would only be desirable if the images would be in folder 1 (for example -> 1 / 1.png).

I am a beginner and do not understand my mistake with the pictures ..

Comment: Are you sure that this is all of your HTML? Because it seems that you are trying to select the image tag by id, but there is no id on the image.

Comment: Yes, this is all. I have not yet defined that with the id, but it's already there. Do I really need it for it to be displayed? Is this the mistake?

Comment: It might be. In this line `const imgTag2 = document.getElementById('img2');` you are trying to find the element with the id `img2`. But when there is no such element with that id, it won't work. Try it out.

Comment: It does not work. It does not have to work for all examples, it is enough if it works for img1. But I have tried it now and it did not work ..

I also tried <img id = 'img1'> </ img> in HTML.
But that did not work either. What does the right HTML code for img1 look like? I also looked in a book, but there was nothing to it. I'm really desperate.

Comment: Write it like this: `<img id="img1" src="" alt=""/>`. Also move your `<script>` tag to the end of the body, before the `</body>`. Because of how the page is loaded, from top to bottom, you will never be able to find any element, because they are simply not there **yet**. So when your `<script>` is at the bottom it will be executed **after** all of the elements before it have been created and rendered.

Comment: Also, do you **have** to use XML? Because there are other ways to create a list of image sources, like plain JavaScript or JSON. XML can be used, but is not the best candidate for this unless you can't use other methods. Please update your code above when you've changed your code in a new attempt.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code now and put the script at the very end. I have also changed bilder.js and taken out the things that are not relevant (hopefully) first.

The ad does not work. I suspect that something is still wrong with the Javascript code?

It must be necessarily XML. There are certainly other ways, but this was explicitly required.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for error messages? It might help you to pinpoint what's the issue with your code. To open the developer console window on Chrome, use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+J (on Windows) or Ctrl+Option+J (on Mac). Alternatively, you can use the Chrome menu in the browser window, select the option "More Tools," and then select "Developer Tools."